# nswindowcontroller + program execution

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cocoa: I've got my user's input - Now what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337930/cocoa-ive-got-my-users-input-now-what)

I am trying to use nswindows controller to handle user inputs during the program execution.
I am able to get the user input in a nstextfield but when i am clicking on the ok or cancel button, their respective IBAction methods are getting executed and the control is not getting returned to the previous execution place  that should execute after the nswindowcontroller gets the user input. Please suggest me a way to get over this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the previous execution place"? Cocoa apps are event-driven, you are pretty much always just responding to user input.

What is your app doing?

Comment: Heres a detailed version of my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337930/nswindowcontroller/1338000#1338000 Sorry for the duplicate post. Thanks